# SQL query to find unreferenced records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables bound through an ID field:

> table1:  id,  name,  type
>
> table2:  id,  id_table1,  date,  status

I have to collect all the records of the `table1` that have a certain value of `type` field and that are not been referenced in `table2` plus all the records of `table1` referenced in `table2` that have a certain `status` field value.

For the first part if I remember correctly I can use the `LEFT JOIN` command:

```
 LEFT JOIN table1.name
 LEFT JOIN table2 
      ON table2.id_table1 = table1.id
 WHERE (table1.value = 'value1') AND (table2.id_table1 IS NULL);
```

but for the second part I'm getting lost...

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and I would like to define a View to handle this.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow the question as its currently worded. Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data?

Comment: The second part sounds like an ordinary `INNER JOIN`. Combine them with `UNION` to get both results.

Comment: @Barmar the second part was much like the second part of the UNION provided by Cl_3518233 (just below) but for some reason the resulting rows were not those I expected to be ... but I was probably expecting the wrong set so I tought to have misspelled the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON table2.id_table1 = table1.id
WHERE (t1.type= 'value1' AND t2.id IS NULL)
  OR (t2.status = 'certain status' )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could just change the WHERE to:

```
WHERE (table1.value = 'value1') 
   AND (table2.id_table1 IS NULL 
        OR 
        ([the other table2 status criteria)
       )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.*
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id_Table1
WHERE T1.Value = 'value1' AND T2.id_table1 IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT T1.*,T2.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id_Table1

WHERE T2.Status= 'Status Criteria'
```